# How to retrieve the value of an Input field and use it to modify a placeholder in a LibreOffice Basic macro?

Tags: macros, libreoffice, libreoffice-basic

I've spent two days on this and I'm still not able to figure it out 8-)

I have a LibreOffice Writer document with some `Placeholders` (`Insert -> Fields -> More Fields -> Functions -> Placeholder` -> `Image`) and `Input fields` (`Insert -> Fields -> More Fieds -> Functions -> Input field`) and I need to retrieve the value of an `Input field` and use it to replace a specified `Placeholder` in the same document.

To be more precise. I have an `Input field` where I enter for example `123`
and somewhere in the document is a button, which triggers a macro, and this macro should:

1. retrieve the current value of the specified (named?) `Input field` ("123"),
2. "replace" a specified (named?) `Placeholder` with an image loaded from `http://domain.tld/image/123.png`

Is this somehow possible? Would be great, because I'm trying to to insert externally generated barcodes into my document...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are both "Text fields", and some information and macro examples are in Andrew Pitonyak's book OpenOffice Macros Explained (available as a free pdf download from http://www.pitonyak.org/oo.php).  The [wiki page](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/Text/Text_Fields) also has some good background.

Form controls (from the toolbar "Form controls") are named, so they have an advantage when working with macros.  Text fields, however - the kind you have in your document - are not named, so you have to cycle through all the fields in a document, or highlight a particular run of text and cycle through the field within the highlighted area to find the one you are after.  The Pitonyak document has examples of both methods.

Assuming the document has only one input field, this StarBasic code will print its current value:

```
Sub DisplayFields

Dim oEnum As Object
Dim oField As Object

oEnum = ThisComponent.getTextFields().createEnumeration()
Do While oEnum.hasMoreElements()
    oField = oEnum.nextElement()
    If oField.getPresentation(True) = "Input field" Then
        Print "Input field contents: " & oField.getPresentation(False)
        Exit Do
    End If
Loop

End Sub
```

As far as I can tell, there is no API to replace a placeholder with its designated content.  There might be a way with the dispatcher - the [list of dispatch commands](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Framework/Article/OpenOffice.org_3.x_Commands) tantalizingly includes "FieldDialog" - but I wasn't able to find any documentation or examples.

I think what you'd have to do is find the field, put your cursor there, insert the image, then delete the placeholder field.  Some more StarBasic code (again, assuming there's only a single placeholder field in the document):

```
Sub InsertImage

Dim oEnum As Object
Dim oField As Object
Dim oAnchor As Object
Dim oText As Object
Dim oCursor As Object
Dim FileName As String
Dim FileURL As String
Dim objTextGraphicObject As Object

oEnum = ThisComponent.getTextFields().createEnumeration()
Do While oEnum.hasMoreElements()
    oField = oEnum.nextElement()
    If oField.getPresentation(True) = "Placeholder" Then
        oAnchor = oField.Anchor
        oText = oAnchor.getText()
        oCursor = oText.createTextCursorByRange(oAnchor.getEnd)

        FileName = "C:\after zoo.JPG"
        FileURL = convertToURL(FileName)
        objTextGraphicObject = ThisComponent.createInstance("com.sun.star.text.TextGraphicObject") 

        REM Optional to set the size
'       Dim objSize as New com.sun.star.awt.Size
'       objSize.Width = 3530
'       objSize.Height = 1550
'       objTextGraphicObject.setSize(objSize)
        objTextGraphicObject.GraphicURL = FileURL
        oText.insertTextContent(oCursor.Start, objTextGraphicObject, false)

        oField.dispose()
        Exit Do
    End If
Loop

End Sub
```